Saving Settings window not Responding on Latest Android IDE
I'm experiencing an issue with Android Studio Ladybug (2024.2.1 Patch 2) on the latest Android SDK version. Android Studio becomes unresponsive,This issue occurs repeatedly.
The problem happen when I close any current IDE
Environment:
Android Studio Version: Ladybug 2024.2.1 Patch 2
Operating System: Windows 11
Android SDK Version: (API 34)


I have the same issue with MacOS 15.1.1 and Macbook Pro M3 Pro.
After updating to Android studio Ladybug 2024.2.1 Patch 2, it repeatedly did not respond and I had to force quit it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
